# failed to load registered .Net provider after publish on the server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, npgsql

im using MVC3 and postgressql i have the following in my webconfig:

```
    <DbProviderFactories>
  <!--for EF4.x and EF6.0.x-->
  <!--you may need this. if you don't modify machine.config-->
  <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
  <add name="Npgsql - .Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=2.2.7.0, Culture=neutral" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

after publish i get Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider,where should i look?why its working on my pc and not after the publish on server?

Comment: Have you already read this issue: [Failed to find or load the registered .NET Data Provider](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/947)? Also check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340997/trying-to-using-ef-6-with-postgresql-failed-to-find-or-load-the-registered-ne.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto mine is entityframework 4 and MVC3 ,non the mentioned woks